# How to find inner elements in appium

Tags: android, xpath, appium

In my page i have these some `android.widget.FrameLayout` I want to check if a specific element `android.widget.ImageView` exist in the `FrameLayout` that have `index=1` the following [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBO7R.png) show the structure of my page
I try the following code but not work 
`driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("android.widget.FrameLayout"))..FindElement(By.ClassName("android.widget.ImageView[@index='1']"));`

how can i get the correct xpath for this element  ?

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible XPath expression to find the target `android.widget.ImageView` element :

```
//android.widget.FrameLayout//android.widget.ImageView[@index='1']
```

and make sure to specify that the selector being used is XPath (`By.XPath()`), not class name or anything else.